# Office 365 Visio UML alternative fragment resize and drawing on grid

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml

Sometimes  wonder if I am just stupid, or if Visio has been designed too complex, with as a result that simple things are just not possible. Maybe somebody can enlighten me here.

When placing an alternative fragment on an UML sequence diagram, I am unable to resize. Setting all lock items in the shapesheet to 0 does not help either. 'Other fragment' or 'optional fragment' does not show this behaviour.

grid behaviour
Often in visio I find myself strugling to draw straight lines. For many simple drawings, having a fixed grid (which does not change on zoom) and adhering to this grid would be sufficient. I expected this is done by switching off 'dynamic grid' and in the 'snap and glue' settings select both 'snap' and 'snap to grid' and leave all others unselected.

When I try this, the grid still is affected by the zoom ratio and I am still able to draw lines which are not on the grid. Visio has approximately 30 options related to snap and glue, but it seems just not possible to have fixed grid and stick to that (which imho is the first basic option each drawing program must have)

Am I asking the impossible here, or are there some settings I overlook ?

Just one thing to add. While just drawing a message in an UML sequence diagram (having only 'snap to grid' enabled as mentioned above). I am unable to draw the message between 2 object life lines. For some reason the message wants to attach itself to an invisible point somewhere in the horizontal center of an 'optional fragment'. 
This behaviour even does not change when setting all sliders (except grid) in the advanced tab to minimal 'snap strength'.

Comment: I'm frustrated with this too.  I am trying to resize the top portion of an alternative fragment and seem to be unable to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found trick, by trial and error. The alternative fragment at Visio contains two rectangle: upper one and lower one. Just click at condition text and resize individual rectangle. The outer rectangle will auto-resize to accommodate both of them. Thanks.